# How can I configure PhpStorm to behave consistently regarding white spaces?

Tags: phpstorm

When I create projects in PhpStorm some files have spaces for tabs and some have tabs.
I have checked show whitespaces in `settings > editor > appearance` - which I am assuming I supposed to be a IDE level setting, but still the behaviour is inconsistent.
Also if a file is created by an external source, PhpStorm seems to adopt whatever spacing the file has also.
Even after enabling `use tabs` Phpstorm uses spaces, is this because Phpstorm is using a file-specific configuration - which is overriding both the project level and IDE level settings?
Does Phpstorm have any option which allows you to define a setting - e.g. `use tabs` and have the setting apply to all files, even if they were generated by a program which used spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: Have you disabled `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` option in Settings? And a side note: settings for PHP have priority over General

Comment: *"I have checked show whitespaces in settings > editor > appearance - which I am assuming I supposed to be a IDE level setting, but still the behaviour is inconsistent."* So .... are you saying that in one file it shows you whitespace characters and in another it does not?

Comment: thanks for reply @LazyOne, Whats happenning is if I opened a file  which had been generated externally (e.g, shell script, imported etc) - and I knew  it only contained tabs  -  Phpstorm would display the code in the editor window as if it had spaces in some place and tabs in others. I think this was caused by some type of caching Phpstorm would do - where it was only aware of the code it was creating. Closing and reopening Phpstorm would cause Phpstorm to maybe read the file properly? but not something I want to do constantly

Comment: I also  went into `settings->system settings` and unchecked `syncronize files on frame deactivation` in the hope that Phpstorm might alert me to what its doing - so I can try and intercept and correct its behaviour. Im finding its giving me the option to reload files - which is working regarding displaying code correctly.  Regarding actually writing new code into the file - Phpstorm is just using spaces - regardless of whether  `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` is disabled or `editor->code style->use tab character` for default indent is checked

Comment: Once again: there are special settings for PHP --- they will override General/Defaults. In any case: do you have `.editorconfig` files anywhere in your project? And please clarify what you mean by "it uses spaces anyway" -- is it happening when you adding new / reformatting existing code .. or what? Screenshots of such "contains tabs only" file please. If you can -- share such file as well (just in case)

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the assist, indeed you are strong with the Phpstorm force, as the Emperor has forseen.... I think I got it sorted, I had selected the "use tabs" option for PHP as you advised *settings for PHP have a priority over general* but I didnt realise that same effect occurs for other file types too, e.g. javascript. My PhpStorm seems to default to `use tabs = unchecked` on **all** the file specific configs, so I found I  needed to use `use tabs = checked/true` on **every** file specific sub-config setting for all the different file types.

Comment: Just adding a note here that helped me, I had PHP code style set to use tabs, but I was editing a foo.blade.php template and it kept using spaces! There is a Blade code style too which was not set to use tabs :) Hope that helps someone else!